# How to import own packages

Tags: python, import, module, package

This is the structure of my files:

```
D:\projects
  -projects\bin
    -bin\__init__.py
    -bin\app.py

  -projects\test
    -test\app_test.py

  -projects\__init__.py
```

I want to use app.py in my app_test files, and I write:

```
from bin.app import app
```

But it seems this doesn't work.

How can I organize my files and import my own modules?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a:

```
__init__.py
```

file in the root directory. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) will explain more of why you need it, and the contents of such file.

Regards,

Comment: I understand why I should write such files. But is it right in powershell:          PS D:\projects> python tests/app_test.py

Comment: If you want to solve it the easy way you can add the path `(..\\bin\\)` using `sys.path.append` and then importing the `app.py` module